# Linked List in Contiguous Memory Space

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, linked-list

I have been looking into some code for measuring latencies and one of the methods I came across deals with iterating through a linked list that is confined to a dynamically allocated memory space. I understand traditional linked lists pretty well and I understand dynamically allocated arrays, but putting the two together is throwing me through a loop. This may seem like a relatively basic question but I am not great with c and for whatever reason I am having a hard time constructing it.

I wanted to make strides of 128 bytes so I tried doing the following (I know I am probably way off base but I needed to start somewhere)

```
char** randomArray = malloc(accessSize);    //allocate space for linked list
char** start=randomArray;               //header for base adress
char** iterate;                         //iterator
char** end =randomArray+accessSize;     //end address
for(iterate=start; iterate < end; iterate+=128){
    *iterate = iterate+128;                 //step through in strides of 128 bytes, assign next addr to current value
}

*iterate=start;     //linked list is circular, assign last element to first
```

I had no idea what data type to point to, normally you allocate space for a struct but that space already exists.

I then thought I would iterate through it as follows

```
for(counter = 0; counter < LotsOfAccess; counter++){
     start = (char**) *start;
}
```

Well this didn't even work slightly for me and I can't seem to find out why. Does any have any suggestions for the proper way of implementing this or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How to think about it: instead of using malloc for each list item, you instead use your own custom allocator.  This custom allocator will allocate items (list entries) from an array.  Each item in the array (in this case) is 128 bytes.  In other words, if you know how to solve this problem with malloc, just replace malloc with my_malloc.

Comment: @jdigital no each item isn't 128 bytes. Each chunk it `128 * sizeof(char*)`, so unless your pointers are 1-byte each (and they're not) the segments aren't 128 bytes long.

Comment: @WhozCraig make the item size whatever you want, `128 * sizeof(char *)` is fine if that's what you want.  You were reading the code, I was reading the English ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well did't get many bites on this one but I still think its a useful question so I will post what I did!

To create the linked list with strides of 128 bytes in a dynamically allocated space I did:

```
char * randomArray = malloc(accessSize*sizeof(char));
int counter;
char ** head = (char **) randomArray;
char ** iterate = head;
for(counter=0; counter < accessSize; counter+=128){
    (*iterate) = &randomArray[counter+128];
    iterate+=(128/sizeof iterate);
}
*iterate = head;
```

To traverse I did:

```
iterate = head;   
for(counter=0; counter < NUM_ACCESSES; counter++){
    iterate = *iterate;
}
```